# What is the definition of interference vs. noise in radio communication?

Tags: radio, noise, interference

Is it defined by the source or by the nature of the waves?

Can one with some instrument make a reading like "In this room we have this level of interference and this level of noise"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Interference** is generated by other signals (in other circuits or, more likely, in the same circuit), so it's artificial noise. Also the signal itself can generate interference, for instance if there is a conflict between subsequent symbols, or not perfect matching on a transmission line.

**Noise** is everything that is not useful signal, so can be due to interference, temperature, impurities, gamma rays, moon phase or whatever.

So interference is noise but the inverse is not true.